# Update Android Studio 2.0 JDK?

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

I just installed Android Studio 2.0 on OSX 10.11.4. I get this error:

> Running on a JDK8 version affected by drag and drop issues (1.8.0_60
>   through 1.8.0_76). See IDEA-146691 for details, and consider using a
>   JDK outside the problematic range.
>   IDEA-146691 did not help me.

Isn't the JDK bundled with Jetbrains IDEs?  How am I supposed to change it?

My OSX Java is 8 Version 77.

**Solution:**

My fault: Java version in the OSX Settings is NOT the JDK version.
Just download the new JDK as Alessio answered below.

Comment: "My OSX Java is 8 Version 77" It must not be if you are getting this warning. Just download the JDK from Oracle and update the JDK location in Android Studio -> Project Structure. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Update your java to latest version..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same error. Simply download the last release (1.8.0_77) from [Java Official](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and the error will disappear. Probably you don't have the last version if the error still shows up, check the version via terminal `javac -version`

Answer (score 1):

See [IDEA-146691 Drag and Drop (to move file) Dialog frozen - escape exits](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146691) for details, and consider using a JDK outside the problematic range.

See [Issue 201716:  Buttons in move dialog not working](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=201716)